# jquery validate only numbers between 5-60

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, validation

I am trying to validate numbers between 5-60

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <input type="text" name="gd_time" id="gd_time" placeholder="Should b/w 5 to 60 " class="form-control">
</div>
```

i have tried this script but not working:

```
//gd time
var gd_time = $("#gd_time").val();
var gdtimereg = [1-9]\d*|0\d+;
if((gd_time == '') || (!gdtimereg.test(gd_time))) 
{
    $("#gd_time").css({"border-style": "solid", "border-color": "red" });
    $("#showMessage").html('Please enter the gd time should be 5 to 60 minutes');
    $("#gd_time").focus();
    return false;
} 
else{
    $("#gd_time").css({"border-style": "solid","border-color": "#E9E9E9"});
}
```

Comment: Convert the value to Number using `Number()`. Use code `if (num >= 5 && num <= 60) { valid } else { invalid }`

Comment: Regex should be surrounded by `/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the value into a [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) and validate it using a `if` statement.

Check below example.

```js
//gd time
var gd_time = new Number($("#gd_time").val());

if (gd_time >= 5 && gd_time <= 60) {
  $("#gd_time").css({
    "border-style": "solid",
    "border-color": "#E9E9E9"
  });
} else {
  $("#gd_time").css({
    "border-style": "solid",
    "border-color": "red"
  });
  $("#showMessage").html('Please enter the gd time should be 5 to 60 minutes');
  $("#gd_time").focus();
}
```

```css
input {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="gd_time" />
```